# Do egg-whites dry as right-handed helices?

Tags: proteins, eggs

Do egg-whites dried at cool temperatures form mostly right-handed helices, and if so is there an explanation for this? Because there is so much (mostly crystal-related) research a quick search did not turn up anything. Below is an image at low magnification (400x).

[image]

Maybe the coiling reflects aggregate properties of proteins that make up the albumin? If someone has a cite that would be welcome.

Edit: different spiral from same batch. This one apparently left-handed.

[image]

Comment: It could be something unrelated to biology - like rotation of the Earth.

Comment: @RogerVadim: In that case Australians should see left-handed helices...maybe so.

Comment: Forgive my pedantry, but isn't this a left-hand spiral? (Growing from the center that is). Related paper [gravity](https://www.jstage.jst.go.jp/article/bss/11/4/11_4_339/_pdf/-char/en).

Comment: @ARogueAnt::  that's a good question. it appears to me that that spiral travels toward the slide (away from the viewer). if that is true we have to begin at the closer end and follow it away (clockwise). if we begin at the center and assume it's going away from us then yes, it's left-hand. the visual evidence--(1) the larger coils are closer and (2) they cover some of the smaller ones. but i am not certain.

Comment: instead of anonymous downvotes, maybe let me know how i can improve the question?

Comment: @daniel I tried fighting against downvoting and particularly anonymous downvoting. [Here is my highest downvoted metapost on the subject](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/13635/247642) ;)

Comment: @RogerVadim: Wow. Nicely downvoted! I was thinking of posting on meta- but you have expressed my opinion for me.

Comment: @RogerVadim: The one virtue of anonymous downvoting is that it gets one used to the real world, in which reputations are made and unmade in secret meetings.